# Why is the index set of all partial computable functions computable

Tags: discrete-mathematics, computability

While reading the statement of Rice's Theorem I noticed that it says "Let $A$ be the index set of any set of partial computable functions $C$, if $A$ is computable then $C$ is $\emptyset$ or the set of all partial computable functions". The theorem itself, and its proof are rather easy to understand, and it is trivial that $A$ is computable when $C=\emptyset$, but how can we show that $A$ is computable when $C$ is the set of all partial computable functions? It is known that the set of indices of all partial computable functions is c.e. But it seems that this doesn't lead to the computability of $A$?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're talking about with your second-to-last sentence. Feel like there must be a misconception or terminology clash of some kind. The set of all indices of partial computable functions is $\mathbb N.$

Comment: (Maybe you are confusing the fact that "the partial computable functions are computably enumerable" with "the set of indices of partial computable functions is computably enumerable". The indices aren't the partial functions themselves, they are their indices in some fixed computable enumeration of the partial computable functions.) [See here.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Index_set_(computability))

Comment: Yeah, I think you are correct, so I should say "the set of all partial computable functions is c.e.". So if $C$ is the set of all partial computable functions, then $A$ is computable because it is consequently the set of natural numbers?

Comment: Yes, that’s right.